# UI Component for Launching ListView with onActivityResult

Tags: android, user-interface, listview

I have this SearchMenuActivity that has a bunch of options the user can select. Two of the options fires an intent to a ListView where the user can select a value and then it reports back to the SearchMenuActivity. I also have another option like this except it allows the user to select multiply options. The problem that I am having is choosing a UI component that will launch the ListActivity and hold the results when it reports back via onActivityResult. I have come up with a couple solutions here they are ...

**Solution 1**

Use a button which default text is "Choose item a". This will launch the ListView and then when the user selects an item the text of the button will become the selection.

**Solution 2**

Use a spinner. The problem with this is that spinners do not support multi selection items. It would also complicate things because the items in the list view are being pulled from a server backend and displaying a loading message on top of the spinner would look ugly.

**Solution 3**

Have a clickable textview which default text is "Click here to select item". This will launch the ListView and then when the user selects an item the text of the textview will become the selection.

Right now I am implemented solution 3. The "Click here to select item" seems intrusive. Anyone have any ideas as to what is the best method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 3** is the best

However it is not very nice for *changing his choice*. I think you must add a small icon to the right of the TextView that allows the user to re-select.

Comment: I don't you understood my question. I am looking for a UI component. Please reread it and if you still don't understand i wil edit it to make it more clear.